# Incremental copy data from AWS RDS hosted MariaDB to blob storage without write access

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I do not have write access to Mariadb hosted on AWS RDS. I want incremental copy of data to blob storage. I can't use watermark or last modified technique. CDC technology is not enabled as well.

I also can't use dataflows because its not supported for mariadb in ADF. Anything that can be done?

Thanks.

Tried, using create command, dataflows

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have much control over your source AWS Maria DB and also Dataflow isn't an option, you may consider switching your solution to Azure Databricks and write a logic using pyspark similar to that of the implementation explained in this tutorial - Data Flows: [How to capture changed data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GACpvMjOJgE)

You may explore writing similar custom logic in Python and execute that using Azure Function activity or a Custom activity in ADF.